# How to use custom tap with libvirt?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, libvirt

i need help about one issue that i cannot understand.
I have some virtual machines that runs on an embedded device, i create dynamically one vm and after i start this one for load some parameters inside that. The network take an ip from dhcp server without problem, you can see the qemu command that i use:

```
qemu-system-aarch64  \
-cpu host \
-machine type=virt \
-enable-kvm \
-nographic \
-smp 1 \
-m 64 \
-serial stdio \
-monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:4448,server,nowait \
-kernel ./Image \
-append 'console=ttyAMA0 earlyprintk=pl011,0x1c090000 loglevel=9 root=/dev/vda rw rootwait' \
-drive file=./rootfs.ext4,if=none,format=raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
-netdev tap,id=eth0,script=no,ifname=tap0 \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=eth0,mac=00:16:35:AF:94:00
```

Before to start the vm i create one tap interface connected to a bridge, where the phisical interface eth0 is also connected to bridge.
Everything is working with qemu, but i need to use libvirt to manage the vms and i don't understand how can i use my tap interface with libvirt. I try to use the default bridge which is generated from virtual manager, it's working but libvirt generate a random mac address for the internal interface of vm. And I need to set manually the mac address like qemu command.

Comment: You've not shown what current libvirt XML configuration you've tried to create, so we can't tell you what is still missing.  The 'virt-install' command has an "--import" argument to aid in configuring a libvirt guest with a pre-existing disk image that should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Daniel, i solved the problems and this is my actually configuration:
You have to be sure the `/etc/sysctl.conf` contains the following lines

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Than i have created new macvtap interface

```
sudo ip link add link eth0 name macvtap0 type macvtap mode bridge
sudo ip link set macvtap0 address 1a:46:0b:ca:bc:7b up
sudo ip link show macvtap0
```

Qemu command for x86_64 vm with macvtap network

```
qemu-system-aarch64  \
 -cpu host \
 -machine type=virt \
 -enable-kvm \
 -nographic \
 -smp 1 \
 -m 64 \
 -serial stdio \
 -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:4448,server,nowait \
 -kernel ./Image \
 -append 'console=ttyAMA0 earlyprintk=pl011,0x1c090000 loglevel=9 root=/dev/vda rw rootwait' \
 -drive file=./rootfs.ext4,if=none,format=raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
 -netdev tap,id=eth0,script=no,ifname=tap9 \
 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=eth0,mac=00:16:35:AF:94:4B
```

Where `tap9` in my case is the tap that is been created from macvtap interface. So with qemu-kvm it's working.
Now I show you the xml that i have created for libvirt

```
<domain type="kvm">
<name>vmdhcp</name>
<memory unit='KiB'>55200</memory>
<currentMemory unit='KiB'>55200</currentMemory>
<vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
<os>
  <type arch='aarch64' machine='virt'>hvm</type>
  <kernel>/var/lib/libvirt/images/Image</kernel>
  <cmdline>root=/dev/vda</cmdline>
  <boot dev='hd'/>
</os>
<cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
  <model fallback='allow'>host</model>
</cpu>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
<devices>
  <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64</emulator>
  <disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/rootfs.ext4'/>
    <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  </disk>
  <interface type='direct'>
    <mac address='00:16:00:7b:4b:8c'/> 
    <source dev='eth0' mode='bridge'/>
    <model type='virtio'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
  </interface>
  <serial type='pty'>
    <target port='0'/>
  </serial>
  <console type='pty'>
    <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  </console>
</devices>
```

With libvirt you don't need to create manually macvtap interfaces, because with this configuration libvirt create automatically one macvtap interface connected to `eth0` physical interface, one for each vm running.
So, i hope that this explanation is helpful for other users.